# How to create bootable USB using public library computer, I do not have admin privilege to download USB Creator

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive, downloads, unetbootin, usb-creator

The title says it all.  I understand that it is necessary to download creator software in order to install Ubuntu/Xubuntu on my brand new hard drive.  However, the only computer I have access to is the public library computer.  Since I don't have admin privileges, I am finding it difficult to accomplish this necessary first step.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: I'd suggest a friends computer or buy an installation dvd/usb : http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17

Comment: @Serg: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more?  **;-)**  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Comment: Unetbootin might work for a non-admin Windows account -- can't say I've tried it, but I suspect you'll need admin privilege to install it.  Then again, even if you can install it, it might or might not work to give a Ubuntu USB that actually boots; I've had trouble with it producing a USB that looks perfect in file managers, but won't boot.

Answer (score 0):

Copied from comments:

Just buy an installation DVD/USB from: http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17

Comment: Try https://www.osdisc.com to get latest Ubuntu. 15.04 is not even in Ubuntu official shop

Comment: @solsTiCe That's definitely an option but probably many users will be skeptical, as osdisc.com is an outside vendor, while Canonical  is the company behind ubuntu, hence more trustworthy

Comment: @Serg you could use the "Check Integrity" tool of brasero to check your DVD against MD5SUMS.txt from ubuntu site. You need to keep only the relevant line in the file